# how to pass class and data-popup parameters via window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link

```
<a href="#" data-popup=".popup-token" class="open-popup" >SIGN UP</a>
```

this opens a div popup:

```
<div class="popup popup-token"></div>
```

Now I want to open this page from a javascript command and have the popup loaded immediately, how do I do this using :

```
window.location.href = "#!/photos.html";
```

How do I pass the data-popup and class parameters to the new page opened?

Answer (score 0):

Send them as query string:

```
window.location.href = "#!/photos.html?datapopup=.popup-token&class=open-popup";
```

Then, handle them in photos.html using JavaScript.